# Plotting 3 lists of the same size, with individual labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is likely very simple, I apologize in advance, I can't find exactly what I'm looking for :)

I have 6 lists of integers, all the same length.  I want to plot them against each other with different colours on the same graph, where each has its own name in a legend.

Basically, I have

`my_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]`

where each list is just integers.  Then I have

`legend_names = ["line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", "line 6"]`

How do I include both these pieces of information into a matplotlib graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

my_lists = [[i*math.exp(-x/10.) for x in range(10) ] for i in range(1,7)]
legend_names = ["line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", "line 6"]
for ydata, name in zip(my_lists, legend_names):
    plt.plot(ydata, label = name)
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]